# Labels overlapping in jasper report pie chart

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 1.3.2 The labels in the pie charts are overlapping. Is there any setting in iReport by which I can prevent this? I cannot do any code changes at the moment, therefore, I can only use iReport settings/tweaks to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Should we close this question as it is still unanswered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by not sorting the query output. After I removed the order by clause from my query, the labels in the pie-chart didn't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

> Try setting the Position Type of the pie charts to Float in the
>   properties windows. This normal stops overlap.

No, it doesn't. Any ORDER BY must be removed.

Amazingly this problem is still present in iReport/JasperReport/JFreeChart 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Position Type` of the pie charts to `Float` in the properties windows. This normal stops overlap.